# Not able to git commit in Intelij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In Intelij during git commit I am facing some error which is below
I have added username and email in gitconfig file also

```
warning: 'C:/Dev/project' is owned by:
            'S-1-5-32-544'
            but the current user is:
            'S-1-5-21-1606980848-861567501-725345543-2664257'
            --author 'ABC' is not 'Name <email>' and matches no existing author
```

Comment: Is ownership of the repo (at the OS level, not talking about git) set correctly?

Comment: And then it sounds like you are missing configuring git name/email (in IntelliJ?)

Comment: Move project to another partition because  you don't have permission to write on this  partition.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when

- you had previously set "Run as Administrator" option on IntelliJ's shortcut and kept using like that
- but recently upgraded to a new version for example via Jetbrains Toolbox

The installer replaces the shortcut and the "Run as Administrator" option is probably cleared on the new shortcut with which you start IntelliJ.
Restore it and you're good to go.